# Unable to log in after updating

Tags: 14.04, login

I have update the `14.04.01` to `14.04.02` and now I am not able to log in in the GUI using my account (only `guest` session GUI is available) - I am not getting any errors, just a short black screen flash.

I have opened the terminal, log with my account and perform the following commands (I have found them as being solutions in similar questions) but nothing changed:

```
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /home/gotqn
sudo reboot
```

and

```
sudo rm /home/gotqn/. Xauthority*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg
sudo reboot
```

and

```
chown -R gotqn:gotqn /home/gotqn
sudo reboot
```

and

```
sudo apt-get-install ubuntu-session //it was the latest version
sudo reboot
```

Could you advice what to try?

Comment: running "chmod -R ug+rwx" might have broken some things, since not all files were supposed to be read by both the user and the group. One that comes to mind is the .ssh folder, which requires the permissions to be 600 (i.e. +rw-------). Also, you made all files executable, which might not (and probably isn't) desirable at all.

Comment: Could you login, switch to VT1 with Ctrl+
Alt+F1, login using your username and password, run `export DISPLAY=:0` and `compiz --replace`? What do you see?

Comment: @zhongfu I am getting `FATAL could not open display 0`

Comment: Did you enter `DISPLAY=:0` or `DISPLAY=0`?

Comment: The exact error text is `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keycompiz (core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display :0`

Comment: Could you describe the setup of your computer's GPUs? Single NVIDIA/AMD/Intel GPU, or switchable iGPU (Intel/AMD) and dGPU (AMD/NVIDIA)?

Comment: I have not got any external GPUs, the motherboad is `ASUS P8Z7-V LK /Z77/ 1155`. The CPU is `I7-3370`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22958/discussion-between-gotqn-and-zhongfu).